# Does Eren have to be in contact with a titan with royal blood or an eldian with royal blood to activate his founding titan commanding powers?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Supposedly Eren have to be in contact with someone of royal blood to activate his founding titan habilities to command other titans. Does he have to be in contact with a titan with royal blood, or can just be a human non transformed eldian with royal blood to activate those powers?

Comment: As seen in previous episodes Eren activated it without royal blood but people with royal blood can utilise the Founding Titan's complete abilities.

Comment: @Loading... Can you mention said episode where Eren used his Coordinate abilities without touching someone of royal blood?

Comment: Season 2 episode 12

Comment: @Loading... That female titan he punched was of royal blood so he activated his powers. This was already revealed way back in the manga and now revealed in the latest episode of the 3rd season, too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest manga episode it is said that he has to be in contact with a royal blood to activate his power of founding titans and they also proved this when they recalled how the very first time eren was able to control titans, that was when he hit diana(his stepmother,a royal blood) and that time he wasn't in this titan form.
So from this we can say that he just had to be in contact with the royal blood to activate the power of titan